# execution of .zshrc throws erros 1. autoload: command not found syntaxr error ; 2. oh-my-zsh.sh: line 41: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: linux, themes, powerline

Can someone please help not sure I'm not able to change the theme in powerline , only see one theme => 
`ZSH_THEME="agnoster"` or `ZSH_THEME="random"` or `ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"`.

Not sure if it is caused by: `oh-my-zsh.sh`

```
source ~/.zshrc
bash: autoload: command not found
bash: /home/c.p/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 41: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/c.p/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 41: `for plugin ($plugins); do'
```

I have the most `oh-my-zsh.sh` from :

1. `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`
2. `curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | sh`

still no luck ?

When running:

```
>>> source ~/.zshrc
```

```
source ~/.zshrc
bash: autoload: command not found
bash: /home/c.p/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 41: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/c.p/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 41: `for plugin ($plugins);
```

Comment: Those errors suggest you're trying to execute a `zsh` specific script using `bash`. Of course it's not going to work.

Comment: did you check the line 41 in `.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` file. Seems like there is an unwanted single quote (') somewhere.

Comment: @shawn , where and how to run it ? 

-Prakhar  code is all good just cloned from git repository. 

Problem is why not able to change the ZSH Theme ?

Comment: This helps [link](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/8038#issuecomment-517334199)

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps

`$ zsh`

`$ chsh -s $(which zsh)`

restart the system

Run the terminal

Comment: Missing explanation...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the following error while executing `source file path` command after making change in a file. I did the following.
before:

```
qbecal@TC215-TOR-MAC projects % source  ~/.zshrc
-bash: autoload: command not found on mac source
```

After:

```
TC215-TOR-MAC:projects qbecal$ exec zsh
qbecal@TC215-TOR-MAC projects % source  ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Run : `source ~/.zshrc`

It has fixed issue